# Access bitbucket git repo via PHP script from browser

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up my POST hook to automatically update the git repo on the server on each push. This works all fine and when I am user apache on the command line and execute the script, it works all fine - the permissions are set, the ssh keys work and it runs the pull.

But when I try and run the same script via the browser, I get a permission denied error - here the output from the php script in the browser:

```
$ echo $PWD
/var/www/vhosts/dev-build
$ whoami
apache
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org 2>&1
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am the same user 'apache' as on the command line, and there it is all fine - what am I missing?

Comment: try using backticks instead of exec

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the moment you write it all down it becomes clear, but I'll answer here anyway, just in case someone has the same issue:

I did generate the ssh-keys with a passphrase and then stored this passphrase for the current ssh session. However when I logged out and then in again, I realised it asked me for the passphrase again - I though it would save it automatically when I enter it once.

So the php script run from the browser in it's own session, didn't have the passphrase and threw an error.

I regenerated the ssh-keys with an empty passphrase, and voila - all works as expected.